# ngrx reselect Selector createSelector load order (circular) dependencies

Tags: react-redux, ngrx, reselect

I've run into the following errors a couple times when I perform `createSelector` in file B using a `Selector` defined in file A... apparently the `Selector` defined in file A has not been instantiated and I get an `undefined` reference error...

```
Error: Selector creators expect all input-selectors to be functions, instead received the following types: [function, undefined] at getDependencies
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:47281:11) [<root>] at Object.createSelector
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:47299:24) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous>
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:170074:45) [<root>] at __webpack_require__
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:20:30) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous>
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:112827:10) [<root>] at __webpack_require__
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:20:30) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous>
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:112838:20) [<root>] at __webpack_require__
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:20:30) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous>
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:85408:17) [<root>] at __webpack_require__
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:20:30) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous>
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:113264:18) [<root>] at __webpack_require__
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:20:30) [<root>] at Object.<anonymous>
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:28456:10) [<root>] at __webpack_require__
(http://localhost:3000/index.js:20:30) [<root>]
```

Since I've run into this a couple of times my thought is that others would have had similar issues, but searching stackoverflow and the internet has not yielded anything meaningful... which leads me to believe that I have yet another fundamental misunderstanding...

**File A State** (Store/account)

```
export interface State {
  accounts?: IDenormalizedAccount[];
  id?: AccountID;
}
```

**File A Selectors** (Store/account)

```
import * as reportStore from 'Store/report';

const rootExtractor: (applicationState: ApplicationStates) => accountStore.State = (applicationState: ApplicationStates) => {
  if (!applicationState.account) {
    throw new Error('Account state was null or undefined within the application ngrx store');
  }

  return applicationState.account;
};

export const accountsExtractor: (state: accountStore.State) => IDenormalizedAccount[] = (state: accountStore.State) => !!state.accounts ? state.accounts : [];
export const accountsSelector = createSelector(rootExtractor, accountsExtractor);

export const reportAccountsExtractor: (accounts: IDenormalizedAccount[], id: ReportID) => IDenormalizedAccount[] = (accounts: IDenormalizedAccount[], id: ReportID): IDenormalizedAccount[] => !!id ? accounts.filter((account: IDenormalizedAccount) => id === account.reportId) : [];
export const reportAccountsSelector: Selector<any, IDenormalizedAccount[]> = createSelector(accountsSelector, reportStore.reportIdSelector, reportAccountsExtractor);
```

**File B State** (Store/report)

```
export interface State {
  reports: Report[];
  id?: ReportID;
}
```

**File B Selectors** (Store/report)

```
const rootExtractor: (applicationState: ApplicationStates) => reportStore.State = (applicationState: ApplicationStates) => {
  if (!applicationState.report) {
    throw new Error('Report state was null or undefined within the application ngrx store');
  }

  return applicationState.report;
};

export const reportIdExtractor: (state: reportStore.State) => ReportID = (state: reportStore.State): ReportID => !!state.id ? state.id : undefined;
export const reportIdSelector: Selector<any, ReportID> = createSelector(rootExtractor, reportIdExtractor);
```

---

`reportStore.reportIdSelector` (at the last line shown for) File A is flagged as `undefined` when used by `createSelector` to instantiate the `reportAccountsSelector`

---

In the past I've moved or replicated pieces of state between "root" objects in my store, but this isn't DRY --- so, why is my approach failing and is there a better (correct) way to deal with situations where I want to access state from other parts of the application store?

Comment: Search for ES6 circular dependencies, as it seems that's your problem.

Comment: Good suggestion - and because you're not indicating that my approach doesn't make sense (in general) I'm taking that as a good sign...

Comment: My assumption is (was) that as long as there are no circular dependencies everything will resolve - the approach of building a tree of store selectors (and reducers) would be suitable to prevent cross-linking / circularity

Comment: It was a circular dependency as suggested by @cartant - the problem was caused elsewhere in my application store structure... and wow was it difficult to find... I've got to learn to do smaller changes to my store to more easily detect when I'm corrupting the structure.... thanks!